# Shifting left with wrapping whole byte array

Tags: java, arrays

What's the best way to shift left whole byte array by one? I'm starting with byte array of fixed length 32 and would like to get also 32 long byte array but shifted to the left by one. 
Example:

```
Input array -> 01000001 00100000 01010100 01100101

Output array -> 10000010 01000000 10101000 11001010
```

I can use Guava for that if there is a good function for that.

Comment: I don't think you can shift a byte in java, you can only shift an int or a long

Comment: @Akshay for `byte b`, `b << 1` yields an `int`. I guess it implicitly casts to `int` before shifting. Whatever, it's a bit hairy but you could get it right with adequate unit tests.

Comment: Yeah..maybe..might be good to give it a try though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), something like this:

```
byte[] outputArray = new BigInteger(1, inputArray).shiftLeft().toByteArray();
```

Comment: Nice. Guessing at OP's motivation for this, perhaps a `BigInteger` is what they should be using throughout.

Answer (score 0):

How about `System.arraycopy`, followed by zeroing the low-order byte:

```
System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, bytes, 1, 31);
bytes[0] = 0;
```

I haven't tried this, but the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) says nothing to suggest it wouldn't work.

Comment: This would shift by 8 bits. OP wants to shift by one bit. i.e the first bit of `bytes[n]` becomes the last bit of `bytes[n-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick, for shifting the array in-place:

```
public static void shift(byte[] bytes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] <<= 1;
        if (i < bytes.length - 1) {
            bytes[i] |= (bytes[i + 1] >> 7) & 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The `& 1` is to get rid of the pesky sign bit.

If you want the result in a new array, the change is pretty simple.

If you wanted to shift by an arbitrary distance less than 8 it would get a bit more involved.

If you wanted to shift by a distance of 8 or more, then you should use `System.arrayCopy()` to move the bytes by `n - n % 8`, then shift by `n % 8`.